# Disable possible caching of Node.js Orchestrator to return always latest data

Tags: caching, odata, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I want to get the latest data via `odata`. So `https://uipathspace.com/odata/Robots` returns all the robots.

But when I change for instance my robot description:

[image]

and refresh `https://uipathspace.com/odata/Robots`. It shows correctly the updated text:

[image]

But I created an application using the node.js Orchestrator implementation. Here I cannot see the description changes:

[image]

Is there something hardcore cached and if so how to disable it? I am not able to find that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `res.send` is put outside of the callback. So it never waits for the actual finish of the REST api call.

This is the base code where it just took the static result of the first request, it never updated the results:

```
app.get('/robots', function (req, res) {
  ...
  var orchestrator = require('./authenticate');
  var results = {};
  var apiQuery= {};
  orchestrator.get('/odata/Robots', apiQuery, function (err, data) {
    for (row in data) {
      results[i] = 
        { 
          'id' : row.id,
          ...
        };
    }
  });  
  return res.send({results});
});
```

The solution is to **moving** the `res.send({results});` **into** the `orchestrator.get`, then it properly overwrites the results as it waits correctly for the callback:

```
app.get('/robots', function (req, res) {
  ...
  var orchestrator = require('./authenticate');
  var results = {};
  var apiQuery= {};
  orchestrator.get('/odata/Robots', apiQuery, function (err, data) {
    for (row in data) {
      results[i] = 
        { 
          'id' : row.id,
          ...
        };
    }
    return res.send({results});
  });  
});
```